# Getting error while sending array to array_map function

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting an error while sending an array to array_map function. Because that array contains an array inside of that.

```
$arr = array();
$value=array(
    "result"=>$str,
    "rightAnswer"=>$arr,
    "tid"=>$topicId,
    "view"=>$view,
);

$value = array_map('utf8_encode', $value);
```

This shows an error like

Message:  utf8_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: array_map will pass in each individual element value to utf8_encode separately. Not all of the values in array are strings. Judging by the name `$arr`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parameter passed to utf8_encode should be a string. Hope the below callback function helps you to get it work.

```
function encode_data($val){
    if(is_array($val)){
        return $val = array_map('encode_data', $val);
    }else{
        return utf8_encode($val);
    }    
}

$value = array_map('encode_data', $value);
print_r($value);
```

Answer (score -1):

Utf_encode() accept string parameter only and you are sending an array parameter

```
"rightAnswer"=>$arr
```

So thats why it is showing a warning.

```
$arr = '';
$value=array(
    "result"=>$str,
    "rightAnswer"=>$arr,
    "tid"=>$topicId,
    "view"=>$view,
);

$value = array_map('utf8_encode', $value);
```

it will work fine. I just made `$arr = ''` to string